# QPixmap not safe outside GUI thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qpixmap

My program has the main GUI thread to handle the user interface.

Another thread is started to handle the hard work (loops, calculations, etc) without freezing the main GUI.

From my "calculations thread" I am using another module `draw_plots` which only draws and saves many kinds of plots.

```
import draw_plots as plots
    class calculatorThread(QtCore.QThread):
        signal1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)
        signal2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int,int) 
        signal3 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int) 

        def __init__(self,input_file_txt, parameter_file_txt):
            QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
            #and etc etc
```

At some point of this thread I am calling:

```
plots.stacked_barplot(*arguments)
```

Everything works fine, however, I get a message on the screen many many times:

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

Would like to know what am I doing wrong and how to avoid this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you issue the plot command from the calculator thread, which in turn uses a QPixmap to draw the plot - all from inside your calculator thread.

Ideally, you shouldn't draw from the calculator thread, but e.g. emit a signal that you're ready for plotting - and do the plot in the main thread. Maybe along the following lines:

```
class calculatorThread(QtCore.QThread):
    plot_emit = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        self.plot_args = your_calculation()
        self.plot_ready.emit()
```

Outside, connect the `plot_ready` signal to your plot command:

```
calculator.plot_emit.connect(lambda x: 
                             plots.stacked_barplot(*calculator.plot_args))
```

Comment: ok so, basically, if I understood correctly, I should use the `plots.stacked_barplot` statement from inside then main GUI class, and tell the main GUI class "hey you can plot now!!" by using the signal from the `calculator thread`....Am i right?, if it is like that, it sounds relatively easy

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `QImage` if the computation is done in a separate thread. You can also safely access `QImage.bits()` and do your image processing directly working on pixel data (a lot faster).

As the warning is stating clearly, `QPixmap` objects should be used only from the GUI thread. You can convert the computed `QImage` into a `QPixmap` if you really need a `QPixmap` (but you can for example draw `QImage`s directly on a `QPainter`).